# Crear Aplicaciones compatibles Con Window XP

Tags: visual-studio

¿Como puedo hacer compatible mi aplicación de Visual Studio escrita en C# para que pueda ser ejecutada en el sistema operativo de Window xp con el editor de codigo de Visual Studio?

Comment: Tu pregunta es algo *confusa*: ¿ Pasos exactos para generar el ejecutale ? ¿ en el *host* o en el *guest* ? De ser necesario, ¿ como pasaste el archivo de uno a otro ? Además, deberías de etiquetarla con el IDE que usas y el lenguaje; así como está, recibirá poca atención.

Comment: Solo quiero ejecutar mi Programa en una computadora en la cual contenga Window XP

Answer (score -2, accepted):

En tu pregunta no mencionas qué tipo de aplicación C++ o C# estás desarrollando *(windows forms, ASP.NET, etc)*, por lo que voy a asumir que estás creando una aplicación de escritorio *(windows form)*, pero también esta respuesta puede aplicar a aplicaciones de C# de tipo consola.

---

Esta respuesta apunta a programas desarrollados en C# para equipos con sistema operativo Windows XP:

Para que una aplicación de C# funcione en un sistema operativo Windows XP necesitas:

- **Crear tu proyecto el cual debería usar Framework 3.5 o una versión inferior**. Usualmente, el IDE de Visual Studio te muestra el framework por defecto a usar para este proyecto *(justo debajo del campo para asignarle en nombre al proyecto)*.
- **Selecciona la plataforma de objetivo "Platform Target" de tu proyecto a (x86)**; en Visual Studio, selecciona tu proyecto y abre las propiedades del proyecto.

*Ver captura de pantalla:*
[image: Ejemplo configuración proyecto en Visual Studio]

Compila tu proyecto y ejecuta la aplicación.

---

Es posible que, *(dependiendo de tus requerimientos)* puedes para este proyecto usar funcionalidades cuyo framework es 4.0 o mayor, para ello, debes descargar el *(o los)* framework(s) requeridos.

Aquí puedes descargar el [.NET Framework 4.5](https://www.microsoft.com/es-cl/download/details.aspx?id=30653)

Comment: Fue lo primero  que hice antes de realizar esta pregunto y no me funciono ..

Comment: @Diego, ¿hubo algún cambio, sigues teniendo este "error" `No es una aplicación Win32 válida`?, te recomiendo mejorar la redacción de tu pregunta _ya que contiene muy pocos detalles_. Por ejemplo: ¿qué tipo de aplicación estás desarrollando (winforms, ASP.NET...), qué framework tiene el proyecto y tiene instalado el equipo en donde estás ejecutando este programa?...toda esta información es útil para que podamos entender mejor y darte soluciones.

Comment: Si sucede ese mismo error, Utilizo Visual Studio 2015 estoy creando una aplicación de C#  y lo estoy ejecutando desde Windows 10. Tengo  .Net FramerWork 2.0 hasta la versión 4.6

Comment: @Diego, **[edita tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/56416/78)** con esta información. Los comentarios son temporales. Además: `aplicación C#`: ¿windows form o console application?, ¿en qué framework está construido?..

Comment: Ya.. en Los Framework desde 2.0 hasta 4.6 lo compilado para intentarlo hacerlo funcionar..

Answer (score 0):

Para generar ejecutables de xp en visual  studio necesitas cambiar el defaul del plataform toolset a v140_xp.

ver el siguiente articulo: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664861/how-to-target-windows-xp-in-microsoft-visual-studio-c](http://ve%20el%20siguiente%20articulo:%20[enlace]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664861/how-to-target-windows-xp-in-microsoft-visual-studio-c)

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta lo intentare tendrá mas detalles ¿donde esta esa opción?

Comment: ve el siguiente articulo: [enlace]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664861/how-to-target-windows-xp-in-microsoft-visual-studio-c

Comment: No logro encontrar ese Menú ¿Donde estará oculto?

Comment: En visual studio 2017 en el menú de Proyecto propiedades y la opción de conjunto de herramientas de plataforma escoges la versión para xp

Comment: En otras versiones también debe ser una opción de las propiedades del proyecto

Comment: No logro encontrar esa opción...

Comment: Proyecto->Propiedades de <nombre de proyecto>->General->Conjunto de herramientas de la plataforma->Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)

Comment: Agradezco mucho su respuesta pero yo utilizo Visual Studio 2015  y  no tengo la opción "General"

Comment: Acabo de desinstalar la versión 2015 pero los menus son similares

Comment: General es la primera opción arriba de debugging